# Why when marking an icon as a favorite, they are all marked at the same time?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

[image]

As you can see in the image, the problem is that when I mark an icon as a favorite, the others also do so, and the truth is that I don't know how to make each marker independent. I am handling the states with provider. here the model.

```
class HeartIconState with ChangeNotifier {
  Icon _hearticon = const Icon(
    Icons.favorite_border,
  );
  Icon get hearticon => _hearticon;

  void changeHeart() {
    if (_hearticon.icon == Icons.favorite_border) {
      _hearticon = const Icon(
        Icons.favorite,
      );
    } else {
      _hearticon = const Icon(
        Icons.favorite_border,
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set hearticon(Icon value) {
    _hearticon = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

here the way he calls them.

```
Align(
alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
child: IconButton(
icon: Heart.hearticon,
onPressed: Heart.changeHeart,
color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
```

I will also put the whole card in case someone is suddenly interested.

```
Card(
        elevation: 5.0,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
        child: InkWell(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 200.0,
            height: 250.0,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 155.0,
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        imageUrl: url,
                        placeholder: (context, urlImage) =>
                            Container(color: Colors.grey),
                        errorWidget: (context, urlImage, error) =>
                            Center(child: Container(color: Colors.grey)))),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        ubicacion != ""
                            ? Text(ubicacion,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                                maxLines: 1)
                            : Container(),
                        titulo != ""
                            ? Text(titulo,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                maxLines: 2)
                            : Container(),
                        precio != ""
                            ? Text(precio,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                maxLines: 1)
                            : Container(),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Heart.hearticon,
                            onPressed: Heart.changeHeart,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: what scroll widget are you using to render the list of the Card?

Comment: a simple listview with a horizontal scroll.

Comment: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use the same icon for all, you have use separate statefull class for each card like this :

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool isActive = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5.0,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: 200.0,
          height: 250.0,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 155.0,
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      imageUrl: url,
                      placeholder: (context, urlImage) =>
                          Container(color: Colors.grey),
                      errorWidget: (context, urlImage, error) =>
                          Center(child: Container(color: Colors.grey)))),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ubicacion != ""
                          ? Text(ubicacion,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                              maxLines: 1)
                          : Container(),
                      titulo != ""
                          ? Text(titulo,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                              maxLines: 2)
                          : Container(),
                      precio != ""
                          ? Text(precio,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                              maxLines: 1)
                          : Container(),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: isActive? **first Icon** : **second Icon**,
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              isActive = !isActive;
                            });
                          },
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to implement it with provider but it still worked.

Comment: If you want to implement it with the provider, you have to save an integer, that is the index of items in listview and after that you have to check it like this:
 `store_index in the provider == lindex of istview `

Comment: :(  I will not deny that your answer solved the problem for me but with setstate but my question was formulated with provider, however thank you very much only that my objective was to put my knowledge of provider :(